# Ubuntu 22.04 Wifi/Cable keeps geting random disconections and reconections every 5 minutes or so

Tags: networking, drivers, network-manager, internet, ethernet

Im new to this OS, but Im heaving a severe headache trying to fix this wifi/lan cable conectivity issue. Im using a lenovo laptop, with a ethernet card realtek PXE B08 D00 and the internet keeps conecting and disconecting every single time with 5 minutes interval.
I tried deactivating the IPv6 since I read here that causes trouble with old ethernet cards, didnt work. I also tried doing this -sudo apt remove network-manager-gnome network-manager-, didnt work either even more I had to reboot the whole OS because I had no internet no matter what I do.
I dont know what else to do, I read somewhere here that you could set as static IP as a possible solution, havent tried that but its for ubuntu 18.04, so I dont know if that will work either. Help pls

Comment: Look at the network logs with the terminal command: `sudo journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager`. Read `man journalctl`.

Comment: hello in the network logs says manager: NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTED, and then manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING and the disconecting and conecting

Comment: Comments are designed for US to ask YOU questions about your Question. You should [Edit] your question to add information. By updating your Question, and using the formatting buttons, you make all the information available to new readers. People shouldn't have to read a long series of comments to get the whole story. AskUbuntu is a Question and Answer site, not a conversation site. If you have an update, [edit] your Question.  If you have a new question,  [Ask] it.

Comment: I solved by updating the kernels to the versión 18, Ubuntu comes with the versión 15 preinstalled, wich is the cause of the problem.